# How to use Big Cartel filter parameters, specifically for hidden_option_input?

Tags: parameters, e-commerce, bigcartel

I'm having issues using the Big Cartel filter parameters to add a class to a hidden input. The parameters are listed in the documentation here - https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#filters-1 - but they are not used in an example. I'm trying to add a class of 'test' to the hidden option input.

```
      {% if product.has_default_option %}
        {{ product.option | hidden_option_input, class_name='test' }}
      {% else %}
```

I've tried a few other formats but none have resulted in the class name being added. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the parameters as comma separated values, like so:

```
{{ product.option | hidden_option_input, 'testing', 'testing123' }}
```

Will output:

```
<input class="testing123" id="testing" name="cart[add][id]" type="hidden" value="123456">
```